# Tool for managing RasPis with Ubuntu Core?

Tags: update-manager, ubuntu-core, tools

I need to manage 3  ubuntu core RasPis registered to an ubuntu One SSO account. I am looking for an easy way to deploy an app to all of the RasPis at the same time. Some "easy to use" interface would be nice. Is there a tool i missed, while googling?

Comment: Could you tell me how to use ssh for that? I'm new with ssh and ubuntu, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not the simplest to use, but [Saltstack](https://www.saltstack.com/) does pretty much what you're asking for. I use it to manage my Raspberry Pi security cameras from my Ubuntu 16.04 server. It's free, cross-platform, and once configured can be used to install/configure programs, distribute files and verify that services are running from a central master.